# Trying to Install GitHub Kivy Designer on Lubuntu/Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, github, kivy

Trying to install Kivy Designer from:
https://github.com/kivy/kivy-designer

Its instructions use this command:

> pip install -U watchdog pygments docutils jedi gitpython six kivy-garden

But I get an error message in console that it could not create certain directories\files because "permission denied". How can I grant it permission?

Comment: try adding  `sudo` in-front of your command

Comment: A better way is to create a virtualenv and install inside the virtualenv.

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly! I will also look into the virtualenv, albeit, I already have it installed on my system without virtualenv.

Comment: @Matt Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/21055859/486919 for a discussion of why using `sudo` with `pip` is generally a bad idea.

Comment: @edwinskl Thank you, that was convincing enough. I am very new to both Ubuntu and programming, is there a general guide to using virtualenv that you would recommend?

Comment: So, I intalled virtualenv, made a folder called "environments", created a new environment there, activated it, tried to complete the installation within virtualenv but it also requires sudo with pip.... Am I missing something?